# How to change button background image on mouseOver?

Tags: c#, image, button

I have img1, and img2 in my resources. I have easily set btn.backgroundImage as img1 in btn properties. Images paths are: c:\Project\Resources...

Now I don't know how to set btn.backgroundImage to be img2, I want to do it on event "MouseEnter". So I would apreciate complete code, because I am pretty green about this...

I apreciate any given idea...

Comment: For a web UI or a win-form UI?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

In the case of winforms:

If you include the images to your resources you can do it like this, very simple and straight forward:

```
public Form1()
          {
               InitializeComponent();
               button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
               button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
          }

          void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
          }


          void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
          }
```

I would not recommend hardcoding image paths.

As you have altered your question ...

There is no (on)MouseOver in winforms afaik, there are MouseHover and MouseMove events, but if you change image on those, it will not change back, so the MouseEnter + MouseLeave are what you are looking for I think.  Anyway, changing the image on Hover or Move :

```
in the constructor:
button1.MouseHover += new EventHandler(button1_MouseHover); 
button1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(button1_MouseMove);

void button1_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
          {
               this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
          }

          void button1_MouseHover(object sender, EventArgs e)
          {
               this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
          }
```

To add images to your resources: Projectproperties/resources/add/existing file

Comment: @Justin's answer should be used since `MouseMove` will trigger whenever the mouse moves - including when it is still hovering the widget, causing strange behavior

Answer (score 3):

I think something like this:

```
btn.BackgroundImage = Properties.Resources.*Image_Identifier*;
```

Where `*Image_Identifier*` is an identifier of the image in your resources.

Answer (score 2):

I made a quick project in visual studio 2008 for a .net 3.5 C# windows form application and was able to create the following code.  I found events for both the enter and leave methods.

In the InitializeComponent() function.  I added the event handler using the Visual Studio designer.

```
this.button1.MouseLeave += new System.EventHandler( this.button1_MouseLeave );
this.button1.MouseEnter += new System.EventHandler( this.button1_MouseEnter );
```

In the button event handler methods set the background images.

```
/// <summary>
/// Handles the MouseEnter event of the button1 control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void button1_MouseEnter( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
      this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
}

/// <summary>
/// Handles the MouseLeave event of the button1 control.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="sender">The source of the event.</param>
/// <param name="e">The <see cref="System.EventArgs"/> instance containing the event data.</param>
private void button1_MouseLeave( object sender, EventArgs e )
{
       this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a class based on a Button with specific images for MouseHover and MouseDown like this:

```
public class AdvancedImageButton : Button {

  public Image HoverImage { get; set; }
  public Image PlainImage { get; set; }
  public Image PressedImage { get; set; }

  protected override void OnMouseEnter(System.EventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseEnter(e);
    if (HoverImage == null) return;
    if (PlainImage == null) PlainImage = base.Image;
    base.Image = HoverImage;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseLeave(System.EventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseLeave(e);
    if (HoverImage == null) return;
    base.Image = PlainImage;
  }

  protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseEventArgs e) {
    base.OnMouseDown(e);
    if (PressedImage == null) return;
    if (PlainImage == null) PlainImage = base.Image;
    base.Image = PressedImage;
  }
}
```

This solution has a small drawback that I am sure can be fixed: when you need for some reason change the Image property, you will also have to change the PlainImage property also.