# Where to add code?

Tags: windows, image, forms, mouse

I am just starting out with windows forms and I am making a button with a mouseover image change (I know I should probably wait with this untill later) and I found this webpage that describes it.

[How to change button background image on mouseOver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554241/how-to-change-button-background-image-on-mouseover)

and my current code looks like this

```
Public Class Form1
Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

End Sub

Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

End Sub
End Class
```

But I am not sure about where to add the code that is in the link. It gives me error anywhere I put it.

Comment: Why don't you try using the same events from that link?

Comment: The answer in that link is using the MouseEnter and MouseLeave events while your code is using the Click event and the Load event of the form.  The code from the link is in C# and you are using VB.Net, so you can't use it directly, but the hints are there.  Do consider getting a programming tutorial to get you started.

Comment: The code posted in that link is C#, your function headers look like VB.Net, they're different languages so the syntax (what you type) is different so that could explain the errors. I agree with @LarsTech you should check out a programming tutorial because it's going to be an uphill battle until you get the basics.