# How can I use images for switch button in C#

Tags: c#, image, button, mouseover

Please, can you help me how can I change the button image to another on Mouse-over.

**This is base button style**

[image: Base Button]

**This is mouseover button style:**

[image: http://imgur.com/iDrzKOg]

I really thanks for every answers which can help me.

Comment: Try this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554241/how-to-change-button-background-image-on-mouseover

Comment: using web form or winform

Comment: have you tried onmoueover and on mouseout???

Comment: i using winform and puretppc advice works. So really thx.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You would simply attach a MouseHover event to your button and then inside the event you would set your buttons BackgroundImage property to the hover image.

Answer (score 1):

**Submit button:**

```
  <input type="image" title="" class="myclass" src="http://i.imgur.com/qNRRTgN.png" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.myclass:hover {
background: url(http://i.imgur.com/iDrzKOg.png)  no-repeat; border: none;
}
```

## [Working Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P6L3R/)

Answer (score 0):

```
 <img id="img1" runat="server" src="images/image1.jpg" 
        onmouseover="src='images/image1_over.jpg'"
        onmouseout="src='images/image1.jpg'"  />
```

you can use this... this is the simplest one