# How to change the image on a button

Tags: c#, image, winforms, file, button

In my current project, I am trying to make a button change its image when a particular key is pressed. So far, my code looks something like

```
 if (e.KeyCode == Keys.H)
 {
     button1.Image = bitmap.FromFile(C: filename\filename\filename\filename);
 }
```

I don't know if I'm calling the file correctly, or using the right method or class. I'm still fairly new to this, so a simple explanation is probably best, thanks.

Comment: `bitmap.FromFile(@"C:\filename\filename\filename\filename");`

Comment: _"a simple explanation is probably best"_ describing exactly what appears to be the problem with your code

Answer (score 0):

If you include the images to your resources you can do it like this:

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    button1.MouseEnter += new EventHandler(button1_MouseEnter);
    button1.MouseLeave += new EventHandler(button1_MouseLeave);
}
void button1_MouseLeave(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img1));
}
void button1_MouseEnter(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    this.button1.BackgroundImage = ((System.Drawing.Image)(Properties.Resources.img2));
}
```

I would not recommend hardcoding image paths.

For reference i use this link... maybe some other answer help you as well.

Reference: [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554241/how-to-change-button-background-image-on-mouseover)