# WPF Button Content Image Onmouserover change

Tags: wpf, image, button, mouseover

I am using Button's content(not background) as image and want to set another image on mouse over. I am trying to set the content as below but fails.

```
<Button x:Name="Test" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="120" Margin="40,40,0,0" Height="120" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" BorderThickness="0" Click="Test_Click">
<Button.Content>
    <Image Source="Images/Test.png"></Image>                    
</Button.Content>
<Button.Style>
    <Style>
        <Style.Triggers>
            <Trigger Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                <Setter Property="Button.Content" Value=" <Image Source='Images/TestHover.png'></Image> " />
            </Trigger>
        </Style.Triggers>
    </Style>
</Button.Style>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to change button background image on mouseOver?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554241/how-to-change-button-background-image-on-mouseover)

Comment: No, I'm not using background, but content for image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It"s easy ! check `IsMouseover` event for Image not for button. Plus check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2554241/how-to-change-button-background-image-on-mouseover) for different ways to change Image on `MouseOver` event.

```
<Button Name="testBtn" Margin="10 0 0 0" Click="TestBtn_OnClick">
    <Button.Content>
        <Image>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="{x:Type Image}">
                    <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/Apps-Dialog-Close-icon.png"/>
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Source" Value="Resources/basic-grid-with-center-lines-png-14.png"/>
                        </Trigger>
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
    </Button.Content>
</Button>
```

Comment: Using image as background has some issues. Please remove duplicate.

Comment: what kinda issue . i Have tested my solution . And it's working.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try control template

```
<Button Width="100" Height="100">
        <Button.Template>
            <ControlTemplate>
                <Image Name="image" Source="pack://application:,,,/images/1.png"/>
                <ControlTemplate.Triggers>
                    <Trigger  Property="Button.IsMouseOver" Value="true">
                        <Setter Property="Source" TargetName="image" Value="pack://application:,,,/images/2.png"/>
                    </Trigger>
                </ControlTemplate.Triggers>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Button.Template>
    </Button>
```

Comment: I have many such buttons and want to associate related mouseover within Button itself.

Comment: I gave you an idea. You can define control template in style, and use Datatrigger, where you will bind image source from some datacontext (model) etc. Please check how datatrigger binding works.